# Can't get js function to load in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've just started trying to develop a website and I'd like to keep the html and javascript separate if I can. I'm trying to put a marker on a map, have the co-ordinates placed in a text box as part of a form, and have them sent to the database when the user submits the form. The code works when it's all inside the html doc, but when I try to separate it it doesnt work. Well, the map still shows up and I can set a marker on it, but it doesn't capture the co-ordinates.

In the head of the html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapSubmitSighting.js"></script>
<body onload="initMap()">
```

Inside the div where I want the js to execute

```
<div id="map">
 <div class="map" onclick="initMap();"> 
<script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key==initMap"></script>  
    </div>
```

The js file

```
 !function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 54.621277, lng: -6.692649 }
        });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.addListener('click', function(e) {
          placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);

        });
      }

      !function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map

        });
        map.panTo(latLng);
        document.getElementById("lat").value = latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById("lng").value = latLng.lng();

      }
```

I know there's lots wrong with this but if I could just work out how to get the javascript to work it'd be a start. Thank you!

Comment: You are triggering `initMap` 3 times? `body onload="initMap"`, `onclick="initMap()"` and `...&callback=initMap`

Comment: Are you sure you got the right file name `mapSubmitSighting.js`?

Comment: why are you prepending your functions with "!"?

Comment: ya what is that `!` in  `!function initMap() {..`
and try to move `<script type="text/javascript" src="mapSubmitSighting.js"></script>` after your `<script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD72DV80rL8PBw2BTTWOwHV3NPSQdx24D8&callback=initMap"></script> `

Comment: If you really wanna defer scripts and HTML, stop using `onclick`events, and catch the trigger in the javascript instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most part of your code actually works.
Did a few modification though.
Added initial marker position as I noticed that you intended to do this on your sample code.
Also, refactored your code so needed routines will be re-usable.

Please check below.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 50%;
       }
    </style>
    <script src="mapSubmitSighting.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="map"></div>    
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD72DV80rL8PBw2BTTWOwHV3NPSQdx24D8&callback=initMap"></script>

    <br/>
    <div>
      Latitude: <input type="text" id="lat"/><br/><br/>
      Longitude: <input type="text" id="lng"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function initMap() {
  var initialLocation = {lat: 54.621277, lng: -6.692649 };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: initialLocation
  });

  var marker = setMarker(initialLocation, map);
  setTextCoordinates(initialLocation.lat, initialLocation.lng);

  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
  var marker = setMarker(latLng, map);

  map.panTo(latLng);

  setTextCoordinates(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng());
}

function setMarker(latLng, map){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });

  return marker;
}

function setTextCoordinates(lat, lng){
  document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
  document.getElementById("lng").value = lng;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not linking the file correctly.

You can open the developer tools (F12 in Chrome, or just right-click on some part of the page and select Inspect Element) and look at the errors in the console.

Most likely there's a 404 error. Look at the URL of the file, does it match the place where it is supposed to be? Are you missing a folder? Did you forget to upload it? Let us know so we can further assist!

Comment: did you mean F12 in Chrome?

Comment: Got it working but thank you for the advice, I'll try looking for errors in the console from now on too.

Answer (score 0):

You also do not need the ! in the beginning of your js function. This is preventing your html from reading the js file.
 should look like -->

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,`enter code here`
```